# Increase the size of plot in plot.barh

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe df , and need to increase the size of the plot,i am using the following code. Any way to change the font and colour of the plot and lables.

```
df.plot.barh(x='name',y='sales',title='graph');
```

Comment: try
df.plot.barh(x='name',y='sales',title='graph', figsize=(4,4))

Comment: It worked , Any way to change the font and colour of the graphs?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ezer, you can add `figsize(w,l)` to change the plot size
To change the colors, you can add this for specific colors. List of colors is available [here](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Matplotlib/api/colors_api.html)
The font size and style be changed as show in code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle, islice  

colors = list(islice(cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'k']), None, len(df)))
ax= df.plot.barh((x='name',y='sales', figsize(10,5), color=colors)

x.set_title('Graphs', fontname='Franklin Gothic Medium', fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Name', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Sales', fontname='Arial', fontsize=16)
```